# Integrating thirt-party shared library with Python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I need to write a Python program to call some functions and get JSON response (a unicode string) from a third-party shared library. Presumably the library is written in C++. The library has a headers file containing following:

```
#include <string>
#include <ExportLib.h>
// some code ignored here
typedef std::string UString;
using namespace std;
namespace ns1{
class DLL_PUBLIC S_API {
public:
static UString function1();
static UString function2();
// some code ignored here
};
}
```

Here's what I wrote in Python (tried both 2.7 and 3.x):

```
from ctypes import *
lib1 = CDLL('lib1.so')
func1 = lib1.function1
func1.restype = c_wchar_p
result = func1()
print(result)
```

But instead of displaying a JSON, the code shows question marks. I did try following, but I get a segfault:

```
func1.restype = POINTER(c_wchar_p)
result = func1()
result1 = wstring_at(result)
```

Please point me in right direction, as I'm not a very good programmer.

UPD: forgot to mention, that I'm working on a Linux system.
UPD2: To solve this need to use Cython, thanks to erykson

Comment: Does it offer a C API? If not you'll be better off using a compiled interface such as Cython, which IIRC does work with C++ libraries. ctypes is only for libraries that use standard C data types and calling conventions, not C++ types such as `std::string`.

Comment: @eryksun, No, it doesn't have any C API. I did try Cython with a similar result. Should I mention it in this post or discard this post and make a new one describing my Cython attempt?

Comment: I would focus on getting it to work with Cython. ctypes isn't going to help, not without wrapping the C++ library with a compiled C adapter interface. If you need a compiler, you may as well use Cython.

Comment: Thank you, I will try Cython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to eryksun, I've found out that using ctypes with C++ datatypes is not possible. Going to use Cython to solve the problem.